# What version of ffmpeg is bundled inside electron?

Tags: ffmpeg, electron

The prebuilt electron binaries for Windows include the file `ffmpeg.dll`.  How can I determine what version of the underlying ffmpeg library is actually compiled to produce this dll?  I need this information to understand what known vulnerabilities (CVE's, etc) might be in a given version of electron via ffmpeg.

As I understand it, the ffmpeg dll itself is taken from https://github.com/electron/nightlies/releases/ when I download my dependencies (I'm using `electron-prebuilt-compile`).  But I'm not getting a clear picture of what the source for that binary is.  I *think* it might be from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/third_party/ffmpeg/ but then I'm not clear on the relationship of that repo with the original ffmpeg repo (e.g. how often are fixes merged from the ffmpeg repo to the chromium third-party repo, etc.)

I tried searching the content of the dll as per cody's suggestion, but no luck:

```
$ strings ffmpeg.dll  | grep -i ffmp
FFmpeg video codec #1
Huffyuv FFmpeg variant
Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
C:\projects\libchromiumcontent\src\out-x64\static_library\ffmpeg.dll.pdb
ffmpeg.dll


$ strings ffmpeg.dll  | grep -i version
H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1
MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2
MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3
H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
On2 VP6 (Flash version)
On2 VP6 (Flash version, with alpha channel)
old standard qpel (autodetected per FOURCC/version)
direct-qpel-blocksize bug (autodetected per FOURCC/version)
edge padding bug (autodetected per FOURCC/version)
strictly conform to a older more strict version of the spec or reference software
minor_version
premiere_version
quicktime_version
Assume this x264 version if no x264 version found in any SEI
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent a few days working on this myself, and based on that time, this is what I have come up with.

Electron versions specify a version of Chromium that they are using, and Chromium has a fork of FFMPEG that it builds from source to generate the `ffmpeg.dll` file that goes to Electron builds for Windows.  I traced a rough version of FFMPEG from a version of Electron with the following steps:

- Go to https://github.com/electron/electron and find desired version tag (e.g. `v5.0.3`)
- View `DEPS` file, and copy `chromium_version`
- Go to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/[chromium_version] (e.g. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/76.0.3809.22)
- View `DEPS` file, and search for `src/third_party/ffmpeg`
- Copy the Git commit hash at the end of the next line (e.g. `41268576ad9a8b760287101f4f58d0ef468798af`)
- Go to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/third_party/ffmpeg/+/[ffmpeg_commit] (e.g. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/third_party/ffmpeg/+/41268576ad9a8b760287101f4f58d0ef468798af)
- View the `RELEASE` file to get the FFMPEG Release (minor version, with `.git` at the end, e.g. `4.1.git`)
- To get a (maybe) better version down to the patch level, compare the date of the commit against https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ for the closest timestamp match

Seems the reason the `ffmpeg.dll` doesn't have a version is because its built by Chromium from source.

Answer (score 1):

Search for it using `strings`, which is part of GNU `binutils` or available on Windows as a [Sysinternals utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings).

It appears that it simply follows the pattern `FFmpeg version x.x`, as shown below, where I search the `avcodec.dll` that is part of the 4.1 [shared release build](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/ffmpeg-4.1-win64-shared.zip) for Windows:

```
$ strings avcodec-58.dll | grep 'FFmpeg version'
FFmpeg version 4.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on `strings`, that is a good insight.  Unfortunately, the only dll I have is ffmpeg.dll (there is no avcodec dll), and the ffmpeg.dll does not contain this string unfortunately.